# 'IN' query in fusion table

Tags: sql, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

In the following code, i want to add "IN" +Village+. Where to add this condition in the code. Variable village takes value from a drop down list based on that filter should occur.please help me.Village name is a column in my fusion table.
   i.e select 'geometry',villageName from table where querypass > textvalue IN villagename='madurai'

```
function querymape()
        {
        /*variable holds the value*/ 
        var village =document.getElementById('village').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var operatore=document.getElementById('operatorstringe').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var textvaluee=document.getElementById("text-valuee").value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        var querypasse=document.getElementById('query-passe').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");

            {
             layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypasse + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypasse + " " + operatore + " '" + textvaluee + "'"+"AND 'VillageName=+village+'");
            }


    }

/*This is my new code.But its not working.Please help me*/
function querymap()
{
//var villagename='';
var operator=document.getElementById('operatorstring').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
var textvalue=document.getElementById("text-value").value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
var querypass=document.getElementById('query-pass').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
var searchStringe = document.getElementById('Search-stringe').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    {
     layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypass + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypass + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'"+"AND 'VillageName'="+ searchStringe+"");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Multiple conditions can be combined using the keyword "**and**"?
2. You twisted the IN syntax around, it is used when you want to match several values, if you only want to compare to a single value use "**=**" instead

Applied to your query (with IN syntax):

```sql
     select 'geometry',villageName from table where querypass > textvalue and villagename IN ('madurai','another village')
```

With = syntax:

```sql
     select 'geometry',villageName from table where querypass > textvalue and villagename = 'madurai'
```

Comment: This is not working.....layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypasse + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypasse + " " + operatore + " '" + textvaluee + "'"+"AND 'VillageName=+village+'");

Comment: layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypass + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypass + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'"+"AND 'VillageName'="+ searchStringe+"");

Comment: Make sure to surround string parameter with quotes and to name the variables and columns correctly (querypass vs. querypasse, villagename vs. VillageName).  This should work: layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + querypass + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + querypass + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "' AND VillageName = '"+ searchStringe+"'");

Comment: Your welcome! If this answered your question, it'd be nice to mark my answer as the _accepted answer_ :-)